# Implement Stretch="Fill" for a custom framework element in WPF

Tags: c#, xaml, stretch, frameworkelement

I have a custom framework element which is the dual to Polyline. This element is designed to draw the markers at the locations of the points in the polyline and will act as an overlay.

I've successfully drawn the points but am at a loss as how to implement the Stretch="Fill" capability that normals shapes such as Polyline have. My code for the class is below.

If somebody could elighten me on how to add a Stretch capability to this I would appreciate it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using ReactiveUI;

namespace Weingartner.WPF
{
    public class PolyMarkers : FrameworkElement
    {
        static PolyMarkers()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PolyMarkers), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PolyMarkers)));
        }

        public PointCollection Points
        {
            get { return (PointCollection)GetValue(PointsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PointsProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Points.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Points", 
                typeof(PointCollection), 
                typeof(PolyMarkers), 
                new PropertyMetadata(new PointCollection()));

        private VisualCollection Children;

        public PolyMarkers()
        {

            this.WhenAny(t => t.Points, x =>
            {
                return x.Value.Select(p =>
                {
                    return CreateDrawingVisualEllipses(p, 10, 10);
                });

            }).Subscribe(x =>
            {
                foreach (var shape in x)
                {
                    AddVisualChild(shape);
                }
                InvalidateMeasure();
                InvalidateArrange();
                InvalidateVisual();
            });


        }

        private DrawingVisual CreateDrawingVisualEllipses(Point location, int dx, int dy)
        {
            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Maroon, null, location, dx, dy);
            drawingContext.Close();

            return drawingVisual;
        }


        // Provide a required override for the VisualChildrenCount property.
        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get { return Children.Count; }
        }

        // Provide a required override for the GetVisualChild method.
        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= Children.Count)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            return Children[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do would be to wrap a `Viewbox` around your entire element's content and let it handle the scaling for you. If you want to do it at a lower level inside your control you're going to need to override all of the Measure and Arrange methods and do all the scaling manually which can be a lot of (very error-prone) work.

Comment: I think that would also scale the size of the markers which I need to stay constant. I have my own solution which involves using DrawingVisuals and handling the transforms manually. I'll post it tomorrow when it is cleaned up.

Comment: You are correct. Anything drawn inside the Viewbox gets scaled, including text, images, icons, etc.